# Python - Get number of items in list not equal to something

Tags: python

How do you get the number of items that are NOT 204 in this list?

```
data = [204, 204, 204, 500, 204, 204, 500, 500, 204, 404]

number_of_not_204 = any(x != 204 for x in data)

# returns True
print number_of_not_204

# looking to get the number 4 (500, 500, 500, and 404 are not 204)
```

Comment: Or without numpy:   `countNot204 = len(data)-data.count(204)`

Answer (score 6):

You are describing the basic usage of built-in function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> data = [204, 204, 204, 500, 204, 204, 500, 500, 204, 404] 
>>> sum(1 for n in data if n != 204) 
4
```

Comment: I know you know, but can be more simplified (as shown in my answer). :)

Comment: I know.  That's shorter, but less readable imo.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) on generator:

```
number_of_not_204 = sum(x != 204 for x in data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `len()` on new list without `204`:

```
data = [204, 204, 204, 500, 204, 204, 500, 500, 204, 404]
x = len([i for i in data if i != 204])
```

Comment: it's a waste to generate the whole list only to calculate its length.

Comment: @cs95, of course, I've not said that it's the best. For me it's just most obvious.